# iOS Camera Object?

Tags: ios, camera, real-time

I would like to insert an object into my app's main view that uses the iPhone's camera to display what the camera sees and then have a button to take a picture.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [*Camera Programming Topics for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html).